# Open folder vs create new project from existing files, located under shared network drive in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm, iis-8

It's not clear to my why I should use the option in **PhpStorm** to create a new project from existing files instead of just opening a folder and declaring the project directory.

I have a web server installed and I can access it's root by a shared network drive. Now I can just open the a folder in PhpStorm and declare it's root. It will generate a PhpStorm project at the given directory.

But there is also an option to open a new project from existing files (located under shared network drive). My best guess is that this option is the way to go. Is this true and if so, why? Or if it doesn't matter, why doesn't it?

There will be several people using the same shared drive to work in different projects in the webroot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, of course, create a project on mounted network drive via File/Open, but note that this is not officially supported. All IDE functionality is based on the index of the project files which PHPStorm builds when the project is loaded and updates on the fly as you edit your code. To provide efficient coding assistance, PHPStorm needs to re-index code fast, which requires fast access to project files and caches storage. The latter can be ensured only for local files, that is, files that are stored on you hard disk and are accessible through the file system. Sure, mounts are typically in the fast network, but one day some hiccup happen and a user sends a stacktrace and all we see in it is blocking I/O call.

So, the suggested approach is downloading files to your local drive and use deployment configuiration to synchronize local files with remote. See https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Sync+changes+and+automatic+upload+to+a+deployment+server+in+PhpStorm